# Format string with special characters as per convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting

The data I'm dealing with is not clean, as a result it contains unnecessary whitespaces causing issues with my program. I found the following cases:

```
- `chavs .` # (space before full stop)
- `band , this` # (space around comma, should be "band, stop")
- `needs ,continues` # (space before comma, should be "needs, continues")
- `51 %` # (space before percentage, should be "51%"
- `transfer :.` # (space before colon, should be "transfer:."
- `request,DDOS` # (no space around comma, should be "request, DDOS")
- `, , which` # (two commas together, should be ", which"
```

Now for first case, I did it converting to list and then removing space followed by `''.join(arr)`. The data is large, and if I tackle each case by converting to list, it would add a significant overhead. Is there a robust, more universal way of dealing with this kind of cases (maybe a good regex) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say all of these are pretty trivial to fix using the .replace() method on your data, no conversion to list needed. Case 2 can be fixed by a .replace(" ,", ","), for example.

Comment: cases 3 and 6 can be done after this by calling .replace(",", ", ").replace(",  ", ", ")